# How to draw a polygon on a tkinter canvas using a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
shape = Canvas(root)

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_polygon(self, points, colour, posit):
        try:
            shape.delete(self.poly)
        except:
            pass
        self.poly = shape.create_polygon(points, colour, posit)
        self.poly.shape.grid(column=posit[0],row=posit[1])

polygon = GUI()
polygon.create_polygon([150,75,225,0,300,75,225,150],'yellow',[1,2])
```

I'm new to using `tkinter` and classes but I want to make a very simple class to create a regular polygon. The code in this program should delete any polygon previously made and then proceed to make a new polygon when the program is called but I keep getting an error that I don't understand. Also how would you go about drawing a hexagon instead?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//xsvr-02/Students/10SAMP_Al/HW/polygon creator.py", line 19, in <module>
polygon.create_polygon([150,75,225,0,300,75,225,150],'yellow',[1,2])
 File "//xsvr-02/Students/10SAMP_Al/HW/polygon creator.py", line 15, in create_polygon
self.poly = shape.create_polygon(points, colour, posit)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2305, in create_polygon
return self._create('polygon', args, kw)
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2287, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected an even number, got 11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just wrong call parametters.

If you want to change your code, this solution can help you.

Class GUI just inherits from Canvas and doesn't implement anything.

```
from Tkinter import*

root = Tk()

class GUI(Canvas):
    '''inherits Canvas class (all Canvas methodes, attributes will be accessible)
       You can add your customized methods here.
    '''
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master=master, *args, **kwargs)

polygon = GUI(root)
polygon.create_polygon([150,75,225,0,300,75,225,150],     outline='gray', 
            fill='gray', width=2)

polygon.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

For more help add comments.

Comment: Would it be rude to ask for an explanation on how the coordinates work when drawing shapes?

Comment: When you call `create_polygon([150,75,225,0,300,75,225,150]` it starts drawing lines from `(150,75)` to `(225,0)` and so on, at the last it draws line from last point to start point.

Comment: Please note that the `__init__` method is entirely redundant, and not helpful because it stops you passing arguments to `Canvas.__init__()`. By removing it you would ensure that the `__init__` inherited from `Canvas` will be called (with any arguments provided to the call on `GUI`)

Comment: your answer would be much more useful if you described what you changed. Otherwise, we're left comparing your code to the original word-by-word to see what is different.

Comment: Thanks for everything, was slightly confused how python handled the co-ordinates