# Tkinter Canvas polygon object issues

Tags: python, tkinter, polygon

I saw this post:
[How to draw a polygon on a tkinter canvas using a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757316/how-to-draw-a-polygon-on-a-tkinter-canvas-using-a-class)

but when I tried to draw a square:

```
from Tkinter import*

root = Tk()

class GUI(Canvas):
    '''inherits Canvas class (all Canvas methodes, attributes will be accessible)
       You can add your customized methods here.
    '''
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master=master, *args, **kwargs)

polygon = GUI(root)
polygon.create_polygon([0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100], outline='gray', fill='gray', width=2)
polygon.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

i got this:

```
expected even number: got 7
```

Iv'e tried everything that i can think about but I can't get this to work!

Comment: So, have you considered giving an even number of coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `create_polygon` method asks for an even number of arguments, why not provide an even number?

The `create_polygon` method takes arguments of the form `[x0, y0, x1, y1, ...]` with (x0, y0), ... being the vertices of the polygon. Each vertex has 2 coordinates, therefore the number of arguments must be even.

`polygon.create_polygon([0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100], outline='gray', fill='gray', width=2)` should work for a square with vertices `(0,0)`, `(100,0)`, `(100,100)`, `(0,100)`.

Comment: But when i try that, i get some kind of hourglass shape.

Comment: Are you sure that you have 0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100 in exactly this order? It slightly differs from something like 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100 which would give an hourglass shape. (Python 2.7.9)

Comment: oh thanks. im really confused with tkinter polygons right now.

Comment: Does the picture on this [page](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_polygon.html) help? A polygon is defined by the coordinates of its vertices and the lines between successive vertices. Therefore the coordinates must be given in correct order. The coordinates of points (0,0), (100, 0), ... are flattened to [0,0,100,0,...]